# AppleTV gray blank screen after OS update

Tags: appletv

There was an OS update for my AppleTV 4th gen, so I set it to download & install. Everything went as it should with any Apple device, but when it rebooted, there is a gray-ish blank screen and after a few minutes, the screensaver comes on and it looks normal (the screensaver looks normal as in I can see the picture not that the AppleTV works normal and displays the menu).

Here is what I've tried to fix this issue:

- All the steps listed on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200197
- Only the steps from this [guide](https://www.digitaltrends.com/home-theater/common-apple-tv-problems-and-how-to-fix-them/) that don't require accessing the settings since I cannot see anything on the screen.
- Same as above with this [guide](https://appletoolbox.com/what-to-do-if-your-apple-tv-shows-a-blank-or-black-screen/)
- Tried different HDMI cables and ports

So far, nothing I tried from the above steps worked.

Comment: Please mark the answer as “accepted” instead of putting “SOLVED” in the title.

Comment: Allan: 1) It is efficient (at least for me) to visit posts that contain "SOLVED" in the title instead of opening every topic related to the issue I need to solve, and read through the useless suggested solutions that are marked as "answer". 2) I clicked on the check mark and it says I need to wait a few hours. 3) As of right now, it says "8 more minutes".

Comment: There are no posts (if there are, they will be soon edited) with “SOLVED” in the title; it’s simply not the model. As for the time limits, it’s to ensure new users allow ample time for answers to be posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This solution is what worked for me, and might work for you if you ave exhausted every other option.**

I connected the AppleTV to a Windows PC (you can use a Mac if you have one) that has the latest version of iTunes. After the drivers were installed, I clicked on the AppleTV icon on the iTunes app, then "Restore". Doing this will erase everything you have on your AppleTV and you will have to start fresh.